# Suggest a Jquery carousel similar to the following

Tags: jquery, carousel

Can anyone suggest a jquery carousel that gives functionality similar to the one in below link.

http://new.evite.com/#gallery/select_category:category=Housewarming&displayName=Housewarming

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jCoverFlip](http://www.jcoverflip.com/demo). It seems very similar to that carousel. You would want to customize it a bit if say you wanted to have buttons instead of the slide control. There are functions built in to handle it though. Namely: `next(); previous(); last(); first(); current();`. See: [Doc](http://www.jcoverflip.com/documentation/advance-customization).

If that isn't what you are looking for you can choose from a plethora of other JS carousels out there for download. Try checking out lists like this: [60+ Useful jQuery Image Slider Roundup](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/01/jquery-image-slider.html)